# Using PhoneGap Build, it says 'google-services.json is missing' but it's not

Tags: javascript, cordova, push-notification, phonegap, google-play-services

I'm building an app for `Android`, `iOS` and `Windows` Phone using Phonegap Build. To send notifications, I'm using the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) but can't manage to build the apk.

---

In my config.xml, I put this to add google-services.json

```
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
</platform>
```

I get this error from PhoneGap Build even though google-services.json **is in my root folder beside config.xml**

> Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin
>   cannot function without it.
>             Searched Location:
>   /project/src/debug/google-services.json
>   /project/google-services.json

I still don't get why it's not working while it should as it's exactly what's asked to do. Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**Additional infos :**

I'm using phonegap cli-7.1.0 and other cordova plugins beside the push-plugin (2.0.0), here is the list :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.6" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.0.3" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.3" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.7.1" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.3" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.2" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="2.0.1" source="npm" />
```

**EDIT**

It seems that it's an issue with the PhoneGap Build (PGB) version I'm using. The version 2.0.0 of the push-plugin should be build using the new PGB builder. https://blog.phonegap.com/phonegap-7-0-1-now-on-build-and-it-includes-some-important-changes-89087fe465f5

Comment: @VicJordan thanks for downvoting my question because your answer was missing my problem... (and then removing it wtf)

Comment: I didn’t downvote your question. In fact I upvoted

Comment: also mind your language. Respect this community. I deleted my answer because that was not relevant and was not helpful to you in any sense.

Comment: my bad then, it happened at the same time and I jumped to conclusion too fast. Sorry this issue is blocking me for a while now (that's not a good reason to get upset excuse me again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the **EDIT** part of my question, it is related to the builder version of PGB.

After adding to my config.xml`<preference name='pgb-builder-version' value='2' />`, google-services.json is found (I still get an error but it's not related to this file anymore)

Answer (score 2):

For Phonegap Build Cli 8.0.0 and up, the target path is a bit different (it's under `app/`):

```
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
</platform>
```